# Joomla's Dynamic Page title and meta descriptions ( page title and meta auto update from DB chosen fields )

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am trying to add a costume PHP code inside joomla page title and meta descriptions by using NoNumber Soucerer extension but did not worked :(

any idea how can i add costume PHP code in joomla page title and meta descriptions ? or how can i get dynamic values from specific database fields for my joomla page titles and meta descriptions.

kind help would be appreciated please...

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamically metadata with this code:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content' );
```